# Decreasing ratio of two Partial Sums

Tags: calculus

Consider two sequences $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ with the two properties: (1) $a_n, b_n > 0$ for all $n$ and (2) $\sum_n a_n = \sum_n b_n = 1$. In addition,
$$
\frac{a_1}{b_1} > \frac{a_2}{b_2} > \cdots 
$$
that is, $\frac{a_n}{b_n}$ is a decreasing sequence.

Let $A_n = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k$ and $B_n = \sum_{k=1}^n b_k$; the $n$-th partial sum of each sequence.

Then 
$$
\frac{A_n}{B_n}
$$
is also decreasing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$A_n,B_n$ are here increasing sequence of positive real numbers. $$\frac{A_n}{B_n}-\frac{A_{n-1}}{B_{n-1}}=\frac{A_{n-1}+a_n}{B_{n-1}+b_n}-\frac{A_{n-1}}{B_{n-1}}=\frac{a_nB_{n-1}-b_nA_{n-1}}{\cdots}$$Now, $$\frac{A_{n-1}}{B_{n-1}}=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} a_k}{\sum_{k=1}^n b_k}=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{a_k}{b_k}b_k}{\sum_{k=1}^n b_k}\ge \frac{a_{n-1}}{b_{n-1}}>\frac{a_n}{b_n}$$Hence it follows that $\frac{A_n}{B_n}$ is a decreasing sequence too.